# Is there a way to enable a particular Android log level (eg via adb) for ALL tags?

Tags: android, adb

I'm aware of how to enable a log level for a particular tag, but I'd like to enable debug logging for *all* tags - or at very least a subset of the tags (eg all tags that start with X or something). Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how adb works.  Every log is written, for all levels and all tags.  When you run adb it filters the list if you request it to.    So just remove your filters if you aren't seeing something.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok, an answer with information on how to do that would be very helpful!

Comment: Just run adb locat without any other parameters will give you unfiltered logs

Comment: @GabeSechan That isn't the case for me. I have logs wrapped with `if(L.isDebugEnabled(TAG){...}` which I have to explicitly enable using `adb shell setprop log.tag.MYTAG DEBUG`. Maybe I erroneously assumed `isDebugEnabled` is the same thing as the debug logging level?

Comment: I have no idea what L.isDebugEnabled is.  There is no isDebugEnabled on the android Log class.

Comment: But even if there was-  why would you be checking it?  If its a part of the log system, then the log call itself would be responsible for checking, not you.

Comment: @GabeSechan https://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html

Comment: If you aren't using the default Android log classes you really need to specify that.  That is not the default android logging system.  WHy are you running SPring on Android?  That alone is not just unusual, but really weird.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log  is the default Android logging system

Answer (score 0):

For adb all level log can be enabled through a config file.

Like in Bluetooth i have a /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf file in which I can change the level of logs from 1-5.

Certain tags are made false in some false do check that also.